# Does the latest cassandra still support the individual rows to have different columns?

Tags: cassandra

I am new to cassandra, I was looking at the offical document. I can find that the table concept in cassandra is very similar to the RDBMS.

The https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/index.html will teach me how to create table, insert table, etc.

But below is from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cassandra/cassandra_data_model.htm.

It said Unlike relational tables where a column family’s schema is not fixed, Cassandra does not force individual rows to have all the columns.
The following figure shows an example of a Cassandra column family.
[image]

My question I can not find this design in current cassandra, below is the screenshot I run some simple insert command.
[image]

Since I only insert two columns **INSERT INTO emp (emp_id, emp_city) VALUES (5, 'abc')**, so the rest will be set null, it's very similar to general rdbms.

So could you tell me how can I implment the 'different rows have different columns' in the first picture?
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra doesn't insert `null` when you omit data for specific column.  The `null` is returned when you read the data and data is missing.  It's the best to check how the data is laying on the disk using the `sstabledump`. For example, for my data:

```
cqlsh:test> select * from test.st1;

 id | c1   | s1 | v1
----+------+----+------
 10 | null | 10 | null
  1 |    1 |  2 |    1
  1 |    2 |  2 |    1
  2 |   10 |  3 | null

(4 rows)
```

for last row I can see that I don't have actual data, because `cells` is empty:

```
  {
    "partition" : {
      "key" : [ "2" ],
      "position" : 97
    },
    "rows" : [
      {
        "type" : "static_block",
        "position" : 144,
        "cells" : [
          { "name" : "s1", "value" : 3, "tstamp" : "2019-04-12T14:33:47.198445Z" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type" : "row",
        "position" : 144,
        "clustering" : [ 10 ],
        "liveness_info" : { "tstamp" : "2019-04-29T12:49:31.450239Z" },
        "cells" : [ ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

but if I insert `null` explicitly:

```
cqlsh:test> insert into test.st1(id, s1, c1, v1) values (3, 10, 3, null);
```

then I will see it in the data file as tombstone inside the `cells`:

```
  {
    "partition" : {
      "key" : [ "3" ],
      "position" : 0
    },
    "rows" : [
      {
        "type" : "static_block",
        "position" : 39,
        "cells" : [
          { "name" : "s1", "value" : 10, "tstamp" : "2020-07-09T09:19:39.751467Z" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type" : "row",
        "position" : 39,
        "clustering" : [ 3 ],
        "liveness_info" : { "tstamp" : "2020-07-09T09:19:39.751467Z" },
        "cells" : [
          { "name" : "v1", "deletion_info" : { "local_delete_time" : "2020-07-09T09:19:39Z" }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the null explanation, but how to implement 'different row with different columns, like row 1 with column 'a', 'b', 'c', row 2 with column 'c','d','e'?  I know it can not be implemented in rdbms like mysql.

Comment: just use `insert into table (a, b, c) values (...)` and `insert into table (c, d, e) values (...)`

Comment: Thanks, I insert 6 rows of data, and  use sstabledump to export, found that three rows are in md-2-big-Data.db, the other three rows are in md-1-big-Data.db, why?

Comment: because this is how Cassandra works. It doesn't modify data in place, but instead all changes (inserts/updates/deletes) are appended to files, and then data is reconciled during read or compaction. Please read DataStax architecture guide for more details: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/dse-arch/index.html